# Developing a fictionalised Royal family

Tags: technique, dialogue, planning

In my fictional world which is very much like Earth, I have started the development of a royal family who shall appear in meantioned news reports and dialogue (in the fictional world) throught the chapters.

I have two questions about planning ahead

1. Is this controversial?
2. Do they count as 'background characters' if the narrator itself doesn't meet them in person through the course of the story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with 2.

It's up to you - nobody decides *anything* about your manuscript except you. Do you want them to be background characters? Then let them be background characters. Do you want them to play a major part? Then don't let them be background characters.

As for 1,

It would be controversial if you wished it to be so, by assigning certain characteristics borrowed from real life. Say, if you have a royal couple be estranged because the prince wants to be with his mistress, then all of a sudden it becomes possible because the princess is killed in an automobile accident.
See what I mean?

Remember what I just said: **You** should be in control of your narrative. You decide whether you want a character to be in the background or foreground, controversial or safe, and so on